# Prevent video.js sending google analytics data

Tags: javascript, video.js

I use the CDN version of Video.js in my website:

```
<script src='//vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js'></script>
```

I want to use the CDN version, to avoid creating swf files of my videos.

But everytime a page loads it, it sends a google analytics request with the url of the page.

Can I prevent Video.js sending these data?

Comment: not feasible unless you host your own copy of it that you modify to strip it out

Comment: @CrayonViolent What's the point of this request?

Comment: Well I can't definitively answer that since that's not my script, but If I had to take an educated guess, I'd say that 3rd party wants to track how many people/who all is using their script, so they can decide things like server load or whether maintaining it is worth it. Basically, if you make something and distribute it for people to use, it's useful to know if it's actually being used. It's a common practice for 3rd party scripts to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @CrayonViolent is right, the analytics are used to understand usage and decide things like what browsers/devices should be supported, and we hope to expand it to understand common errors that need to fixed as well. But first we need to be more clear about that for CDN users, and we're working on a TOS for the CDN version. CrayonViolent is also right in that the way to avoid the analytics call is to host it yourself. It's not in any other version of video.js.